# Multi Module Project - Assembly plugin

Tags: maven-2, maven-plugin

I am using Maven 2.0.9 to build a multi module project. I have defined the assembly plugin in my parent pom. I can get my assemblies built using

```
mvn install assembly:assembly
```

This command runs the tests twice, once during install phase and another during assembly. I tried assembly:single but it throws an error. Any help to get my assemblies built without running the tests twice is much appreciated.

Comment: Please provide the error. Without it, it's hard to say anything.

Answer (score 7):

Invoking the assembly mojo will cause Maven to build the project using the normal lifecycle, up to the `package` phase. So, when you run:

```
mvn install assembly:assembly
```

you are actually telling maven to run a few things twice and this includes the test phase as you can see in the [documentation](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html#Lifecycle_Reference) of the default lifecycle.

To avoid this,  consider running only:

```
mvn assembly:assembly
```

Or bind the plugin on a project's build lifecycle:

```
<project>
  ...
  <build>
    ...
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
          ...
        </configuration>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>make-assembly</id> <!-- this is used for inheritance merges -->
            <phase>package</phase> <!-- append to the packaging phase. -->
            <goals>
              <goal>single</goal> <!-- goals == mojos -->
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      ...
</project>
```

Comment: Hey, Pascal Thivent:  Your answer helped me understand the differences between mvn install assembly:assembly and mvn assembly:assembly.  Can you help me understand the differences between mvn assembly:assembly and mvn package assembly:assembly?

Answer (score 1):

I think the error message is misleading , it suggests you need to run the "package" phase within the SAME maven invocation as the assembly plugin's invocation itself.

Did you try  "mvn package assembly:assembly" or "mvn install assembly:assembly" ?

Works for me under Linux , JDK 1.6.0_16 , Maven 2.2.1 , Assembly Plugin 2.2-beta-4.

Comment: The POM snippet suggested above (binding assembly plugin to the 'ackage phase) should work equally , just keep in mind that then you don't need to explicitly invoke the assembly plugin on the command line. A 'mvn package' (or 'mvn install')  will automatically create the assembly as well. Not sure if I've ever used the assembly plugin in that way though. I usually invoke it explicitly because I often don't care about the assembly being generated.

Comment: I tied assembly plugin to package or install phase, ram mvn install or mvn package. Still the same error. This happens only in multi module project.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a separate project for assembly in multi-module project.
That separate module will just assembly - and it will have dependencies: siblings that should be added to result assembly.

Please read this article:
http://www.sonatype.com/books/mvnref-book/reference/assemblies-sect-best-practices.html